# Update CA Certs is Removing All Certs/Symlinks

Tags: linux, debian, certificate

I am running a Debian 10 system. I am trying to add an additional cert using the standard process: putting the .crt file under "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates" and running "update-ca-certificates". However, instead of functioning as expected, I get the following:

```
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/LuxTrust_Global_Root_2.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/ePKI_Root_Certification_Authority.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SSL.com_Root_Certification_Authority_ECC.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Trustis_FPS_Root_CA.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Premium_ECC.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GDCA_TrustAUTH_R5_ROOT.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/COMODO_Certification_Authority.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.pem
find: ‘test’: No such file or directory

## Many other lines like above omitted for brevity

Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/IdenTrust_Commercial_Root_CA_1.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/SwissSign_Gold_CA_-_G2.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/IdenTrust_Public_Sector_Root_CA_1.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/Certigna.pem
Removed orphan symlink /etc/ssl/certs/GTS_Root_R2.pem

## Many other lines like above omitted for brevity

Doing .
link ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem -> f6af6c7e.0
139 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/ACCVRAIZ1.pem. Message:
  /etc/ssl/certs/ACCVRAIZ1.pem (No such file or directory)
Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem. Message:
  /etc/ssl/certs/AC_RAIZ_FNMT-RCM.pem (No such file or directory)
Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem. Mes
sage:
  /etc/ssl/certs/Actalis_Authentication_Root_CA.pem (No such file or directory)
Warning: there was a problem reading the certificate file /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem. Message:
  /etc/ssl/certs/AffirmTrust_Commercial.pem (No such file or directory)

## Many other lines like above omitted for brevity
```

It looks like the process is removing my symlinks for some reason. Needless to say, I realize the `find: ‘test’: No such file or directory` are also not normal.

I think it is clear that this is configuration issue; however, I am not sure where to look.  I checked all the files and directories I typically associate with the command ( `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`, `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, `/usr/share/ca-certificates`, and `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`) and nothing seemed amiss.I also tried running `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and reinstalling the package. Nothing worked.

What other scripts or configuration files might influence this commands behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is saying that your system is missing the `test` command, typically found at /usr/bin/test (part of the "coreutils") package.

`test` (also known as `[`, as in `if [ ...`) is both an external command and a shell built-in command – shell scripts normally use the built-in, but other programs only see it as a standalone command. In this case, the update script uses `find ... -exec test ... \;`, which fails to find a command named `test` in $PATH for some reason.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Definitely would not have expected that. Not sure what happened but reinstalling `coreutils` fixed it.